# MVC4: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Actualmente estoy usando MVC4, y desde un `layout` estoy llamando a un `PartialView`:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/PartialView/EditForm.cshtml")
```

Y al ejecutar el aplicativo por primera vez me da este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con la URL del aplicativo de la siguiente forma:

```
localhost:50234
```

Luego, vuelvo a ejecutar el aplicativo y funciona sin errores de `null`. Pero  cambia la URL:

```
http://localhost:50234/PartialView/EditForm
```

Los elementos que generan conflictos son elementos definidos en el `viewmodel` como "catalogos"

```
    public IEnumerable<String> Catalogo1  { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> Catalogo2  { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> Catalogo3  { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> Catalogo4  { get; set; }
```

Mi pregunta es:

- El error se encuentra en la llamada al `PartialView` (considerando que es un `viewmodel`)? Debería hacer la llamada de otra forma?
- Los elementos catálogos creados en en `viewmodel` deberían ir con "get" "set" o deben inicializarse de otra manera?
- Hay alguna forma de ir directamente a la URL del `ActionResult` en la primera ejecución?

Comment: _Como tienes definida tus rutas?_, _Tienes un archivo ViewStart?_ y por ultimo _Como esta programada tu vista que carga tu vista parcial?_

Comment: Las rutas están bien definidas, por eso hago hincapié en que el error sucede en la primera ejecución, en la segunda todo se ejecuta correctamente. Tengo un viewstart que llama al layout. Y la vista, me parece largo de mostrar el codigo, básicamente tengo html helpers que llaman a los catálogos para llenar los combos. Me da la sensación que esta yendo directo a la Vista y trata de obtener los valores de los catálogos antes de que se ejecute el controlador y llene los combos.

Comment: Prueba cambiando la URL por solo el nombre de la vista que quieres llamar

Comment: Me dio el siguiente error: No se encuentra la vista parcial 'EditForm.cshtml' o no hay un motor de búsqueda que admita las ubicaciones de búsqueda. Se buscó en las siguientes ubicaciones: 
~/Views/Home/EditForm.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/Home/EditForm.cshtml.ascx
~/Views/Shared/EditForm.cshtml.aspx
~/Views/Shared/EditForm.cshtml.ascx
~/Views/Home/EditForm.cshtml.cshtml
~/Views/Home/EditForm.cshtml.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/EditForm.cshtml.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/EditForm.cshtml.vbhtml

Comment: Parece que es problema de posicionamiento de la ruta, quita el `Views/` de la ruta del `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: ¿Qúe tienes en el ~/Views/PartialView/EditForm.cshtml? ¿Podrías explicar lo que quieres hacer funcionar por favor? :D

Comment: Tengo html helpers. Entre ellos varios combo box que se alimentan de catalogos. Dichos catalogos los tengo en el viewmodel correspondiente al controlador de la vista y se inicializan cuando llamo al ActionResult EditForm(). El problema lo tengo cuando ejecuto por primera vez, por alguna razon antes de llamar al ActionResult EditForm consulta los datos de los combobox y es ahi cuando da error. Volviendo a ejecutar hace la llamada correctamente y se llenan los combos como corersponde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estaba equivocado en lo que escribi antes... luego de unas 30 ejecuciones volvio a darme el error... volvi a pasar otras horas investigando y se trataba de la clase "RouteConfig.cs" que tenia otros valores seteados. La deje configurada asi y no me pincha mas. Notese que los nombres en ingles son nombres que ya estaban asi definido por el sistema, solo cambie el nombre del controller y del action.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "NombredeMiControlador", action = "NombreDeMiActionResult", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, basicamente el problema residia en el @Html.BeginForm de la vista del partialView:

al usar `@Html.Partial("ruta del partial view")`

trataba de llamar a la vista con catalogos y etc por que era el unico `@Html.BeginForm` definido.

ahora lo que hice es una sobrecarga de `@Html.BeginForm`:

pongo este sin parametros para cuando la llama por primera vez:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

}
```

y abajo pongo el  `@Html.BeginForm` que realmente necesito:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MetodoPost", "Controllador", FormMethod.Post))

{

...

llamadas a catalogos y demas elementos Helpers Html y etc.

...

}
```

entonces el layout trata de ingresar a la vista, se encuentra con el `BeginForm()` sin valores, luego va al `ActionResult` de mi `Controller` y me carga todos los datos del `BeginForm()` con catálogos

Espero que a alguien le sirva la respuesta :)